# Проверка на вхождения объектов одной колллекции в другую

Tags: java, arraylist, сравнение

Как сравнить два `List` между собой без учета порядка расположения элементов в них.
Проблема в том, что сравнение должно происходить не на полное совпадение, а на вхождение.

То есть если, к примеру, 2 элемента одного `List` есть в другом `List` то тогда код должен вернуть `true`, как это реализовать?
Если это важно то оба `List` содержат в себе объекты класса `String`.
То есть в результате сравнения этих двух коллекций:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("Морковь");

list.add("Яйца");

list.add("Сахар");

ArrayList<String> list001 = new ArrayList<String>();

list001.add("Сахар");    

list001.add("Морковь");

list001.add("Верблюд");
```

Должно вернуть `True`. Как это реализовать?

Comment: `list001.containsAll(list)` -_-

Comment: @Suvitruf посмотрите пожалуйста upd, возникли некоторые проблемы

Comment: `list001` не содержит `"Яйца"`, которые есть в `list`.

Comment: А как сделать так, что бы код из upd возвратил `true`?

Comment: Переформулировать вопрос и написать, чего вы хотите на самом деле )

Comment: @Suvitruf попытался. Вроде теперь должно стать понятнее.

Comment: Почему именно 2 элемента? А если в обоих списках будет по 4 элемента, то критерием возврата `true` сколько элементов будет?

Comment: @Suvitruf Эх, похоже все таки немного непонятно объяснил. Суть в том, что если в обоих List'ах есть совпадающие элементы то нужно вернуть `true`

Comment: Хотя бы 1 совпадающий?

Comment: @Suvitruf Да, даже один

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Java 8+, то вот в лоб решение:

```
System.out.println(list001.stream().anyMatch(item1 -> list.stream().anyMatch(item2 -> item1.equals(item2))));
```

`list001.stream().anyMatch` - это, дословно, ищем, есть ли хотя бы один элемент, который...

Внутри идёт условие, которое прогоняется для каждого элемента `item1 -> {...}`.

`list.stream().anyMatch` тоже самое для второго списка.

Если всё резюмировать, то: **смотрим, есть ли в первом списке хотя бы один элемент, который есть во втором списке.**

Comment: А можно еще код без лямбды, а то я ее пока что не понимаю...

Comment: Без лямбд, если самим писать, то вложенными циклами придётся. Некрасиво. Я могу пояснить, что тут происходит, если надо )

Comment: Ну если не сложно, то объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Постарался как смог.

Comment: Все. Вроде понятно, большое спасибо!

Comment: Рад, что помогло. С лямбдами сложно только в самом начале. В какой-то момент вы сможете их без проблем читать и писать. Главное - практиковаться.

Comment: `list001.stream().anyMatch(list::contains)` ?

Comment: @zRrr это ещё меньше понятно :D но лаконичней, да.

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean containsAny = !Collections.disjoint(list, list001);
```

Answer (score 0):

подсчитать количество вхождений каждого элемента в список и сравнить

List first = Arrays.asList( "a", "b", "a" );
List second = Arrays.asList( "a", "a", "b" );

first.stream().collect( groupingBy( k -> k, counting()) )
    .equals( second.stream().collect( groupingBy( k -> k, counting()) ) )